# How to access from "onCreate()" an Arraylist variable in another method of same class?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to access an `Arraylist` variable (**mySongs**) declared globally and used in the `onCreate()` method in another method called `btnNext()`. The value of this variable is taken from another class using `Intent`.

But I'm not able to get the value of that variable in the `btnNext()` method.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle b = i.getExtras();
mySongs = (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("songlist");
position = b.getInt("pos",0);
```

It's giving a null pointer exception on this variable. When checked in the Log, it's showing 'null' in the method whereas when checked on Log outside the `btnNext()` method, it works fine.

```
public void btnNext(){
    Log.d("DATA", "songs"+mySongs);

    if(isRepeat==true || isShuffle==true)
    {
        isRepeat = false;
        btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat_default);

        isShuffle = false;
        btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle_default);
    }
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    position = (position+1) % mySongs.size();
    Log.d("DATA", "p"+position);
    u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);
    displaySongName(position);
    mp.start();
    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Method called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("DATA", "p");    
}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
mySongs = (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("songlist");
```

with this

```
mySongs = new ArrayList<Object>(b.getParcelableArrayList("songlist"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it `public` `static` and you will be able to pass your `ArrayList` to Another Class. But, better way would be to use `Serializable` or `Parcelable` to pass it.

Use it

```
mySongs = new ArrayList<Object>(b.getParcelableArrayList("songlist"));
```

Comment: Madam i think if it was static you should change the code to `Classname.mySongs` and speaking about parcelable i think its already being done

Answer (score 0):

You declared mySongs globally , but have you created its instance in onCreate()?

```
mySongs = new ArrayList(); ?
```

Comment: guess `=` means its pointing to an address, doesn't it? SIr? and `new` means creating a new address

Comment: yup sorry, just saw your answer , argument is missing . 
I will check all the answers before posting one in future :)

Comment: no no Sir, what i mean is he is already pointing to another arraylist so your solution will prevent the NPE but would not give him his preferred arraylist that is all i wanted to say. hope you get me Sir